# Weibull fitting

Tags: nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, weibull-distribution

I'm trying to fit a Weibull curve to my xy data. I know that the 3 Weibull model has 3 parameters, the scale, the shape and the location and I would like to estimate them from my data.

I used curve experts software which gave me the following coefficients:
a, b, c, and d and the following equation: y=a-b*exp(-cx^d).
How can I estimate the scale, the shape and the location parameters from the above coefficients?

Comment: Do you have a random sample from a Weibull distribution or data that suggests the same shape as a Weibull distribution?  If the former, then you should use maximum likelihood rather than what I suspect is least-squares from curve experts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have xy data that have a sigmodal shape and I fitted several sigmoidal model included in curve expert! I found that the Weibull model is the best estimate! Now, I need to estimate the 3 parameters: the scale, the shape and the location for further consideration/analysis

Comment: Can you share the actual coefficients? (a, b, c, and d)

Comment: a = 270.471208
b = 266.989396
c = 0.398497
d = -0.079732

Comment: I understood the meaning of the coefficients that is a= the Asymptote, b= the scale parameter, c= relative growth rate and d = the shape. However I'm worried about the fitting of my data. My data are: x= 5.61;15.60;50.55;140.42;390.06;1263.80;3510.56;8253.72; y = 82.47;76.75;70.99;66.43;62.04;57.40;53.64;50.53. My curve should be descending starting from x= 5.61 y= 82.47 and then decrease until reaching the asymptote. The weibull model give the asymptote at 270.471208 (a) that is the asymptote for the minimum x value but I'm interested at the asymptote for the maximum x value.